# Import cfn-lint report to Jenkins through Warnings-NG plugin

Tags: jenkins, junit, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I'm using [Warnings-NG plugin](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/warnings-ng/) to import all reports generated by Pylint and YamlLint succesfully. Now I want to import the [cfn-lint](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cfn-lint) (cloudformation yaml files) reports but I'm having problems.

I've generated the `cfn-lint` reports using `-f parseable --output-file report.out` and imported it to Jenkins with Warnings-NG's `recordIssues tool: yamlLint(pattern: 'report.out')` without errors, but unfortunately no detected errors in the cloudformation template were imported.

After that, I tried change the format report to Junit and import it using the available Junit tool.

```
// Generate the report:
cfn-lint . -f junit --output-file report-junit.out

// Import the junit report:
recordIssues tool: junitParser(pattern: 'report-junit.out')
```

In this last case I'm having Java errors.

Has anyone tried to import the `cfn-lint` reports into jenkins or another type of application?
Any idea is welcome.
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I raised this issue on [Violations Lib](https://github.com/tomasbjerre/violations-lib/issues/131) to add to support to Cfn-Lint report Junit format, now it was fixed and will be available in the next release of Warnings-NG Jenkins Plugin.

If you don't want wait for it, I created a workaround, it basically takes the `:` (colon) delimited file (`cfn-lint . -f parseable --output-file report.out`) and modify it to format that Warnings-NG [RecordIssues YamlLint](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/warnings-ng/#recordissues-record-compiler-warnings-and-static-analysis-results) expects.

I used this Groovy code to do that:

```
def cfnLogFile = readFile "report.out"
def cfnLogFileRows = cfnLogFile.readLines()
cfnLogLine = ""
for (row in cfnLogFileRows){
  def (c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7) = row.tokenize(":")
  if (c6 ==~ /E.*/){
    level = "[error]"
  } else if (c6 ==~ /W.*/){
    level = "[warning]"
  } else {
    level = "[information]"
  }
  cfnLogLine = c1 + ":" + c2 + ":" + c3 + ": " + level + " " + c6 + " " + c7
sh "echo '${cfnLogLine}' >> report_parsed.out"
}
```

Now, in other step you can upload the `report_parsed.out`:

```
recordIssues(
  enabledForFailure: false,
  tool: yamlLint(pattern: '**/report_parsed.out', reportEncoding: 'UTF-8', id: 'cfn-lint', name: 'Cfn-Lint')
)
```